# RabbitMQ erlang cookies issue

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq

I installed the RabbitMQ server on my machine (windows 7 enterprise) to develop code locally with spring boot. i. e. integrate spring-boot into RabbitMQ. The issue I am running into is that i am unable to basic rabbitmqctl commands such as even listing the exchanges.

It is responding with this:

```
rabbitmqctl list_exchanges
Error: unable to perform an operation on node 'rabbit@hostname'. Please see d
iagnostics information and suggestions below.

Most common reasons for this are:

 * Target node is unreachable (e.g. due to hostname resolution, TCP connection o
r firewall issues)
 * CLI tool fails to authenticate with the server (e.g. due to CLI tool's Erlang
 cookie not matching that of the server)
 * Target node is not running

In addition to the diagnostics info below:

 * See the CLI, clustering and networking guides on http://rabbitmq.com/document
ation.html to learn more
 * Consult server logs on node rabbit@hostname

DIAGNOSTICS
===========

attempted to contact: [rabbit@hostname]

rabbit@hostname:
  * connected to epmd (port 4369) on hostname
  * epmd reports node 'rabbit' uses port 25672 for inter-node and CLI tool traff
ic
  * TCP connection succeeded but Erlang distribution failed

  * Authentication failed (rejected by the remote node), please check the Erlang
 cookie


Current node details:
 * node name: rabbitmqcli28@hostname
 * effective user's home directory: root_to_mo_directory
 * Erlang cookie hash: ERLANG_COOKIE_HASH_GIVEN_HERE
```

any suggestions? how could I approach troubleshooting this?

Comment: This has nothing to do with spring, so I removed the tags; the RabbitMQ engineers hang out on the `rabbitmq-users` google group, so I suggest you ask over there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I searched google using the following terms `site:rabbitmq.com erlang cookie` and the search results included [this document](https://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html#erlang-cookie). It provides comprehensive information on where the Erlang cookie is stored based on operating system and Erlang version.

Since you don't provide information on what Erlang version you're using, I can't tell you specifically where to look.

Once you find the cookie file, copy it to your user's home directory and the `rabbitmqctl` commands should work correctly.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I did